# Features in SVM based Sentiment Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, svm, libsvm

I am unable to convert semantic and lexical information into feature vectors.

I know the following information

- Part of Speech tag - output of POS tagger ex Adjective,verb
- Word Sense- output of Word Sense Disambiguation ex Bank - financial institution,heap
- Ontological information - ex mammal,Location
- n-gram - ex good-boy
- Head word - ex act root word of acting

My question is how to represent them as real values.Should I just just choose the occurrence of each of the feature(POS,sense,etc..) i.e. boolean vector but then the semantic information will be lost in case of n-grams(ex very good boy and good boy have different semantic orientation in case of sentiment analysis).

Comment: Usually you'd use boolean vectors, i.e. a one-hot encoding of the input features.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good method for converting nominal values into real valued vectors. The most common approach is as you suggested - conversion to he boolean vectors. In case of n-grams I do not see your point. What is your object? You say that you have POS, POS is a feature of a **word**, n-gram on the other hand has no meaning on the **single word** level, but rather as a representation of the part of the sentence. Do you mean "n-gram in which it appears"? It is exactly the same as "previous word" then (or n-1 previous words) and you do not loose any information then (simply you have k dimensions per each "previous" word, where k is a size of a vocablurary). Keep in mind, that your representation will be **huge**.

Comment: I agree that my n-gram representation will be huge but then very good boy and good boy has different semantic orientation in case of sentiment analysis. So how should i represent them in order to distinguish between the two

Comment: exactly as I said in the answer, the "previous word" feature is enough, or "previous n words" (each as different set of dimensions). However, there are no "best" answers in ML. This is very complex topic, even in case of a simple problem of sentiment analysis.